# How to add new line in string in Typescript - Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement in typescript the following:

```
this.comments = this.comment1 + '/n' + this.comment2
```

in HTML it is bound as `{{comments}}`.

It should print:

```
comment1
comment2
```

but it prints:

```
comment1/ncomment2
```

I have tried `<br\>` too but it does not work. How to do it?

Comment: i have tried <br\ too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - Creating New Lines in a string using "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220411/typescript-creating-new-lines-in-a-string-using-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the "\n" rather than "/n"

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have been banging my head for this the entire day. It works perfectly. 
Stackoverflow community is awesome :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `innerHTML` and `innerText` directives in any template element for that. Like:

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Hello<br>World';
  weather = 'Super\nsunny\nday';
}
```

HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="name"></div>
<div [innerText]="weather"></div>
```

Demo for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chusrl

Answer (score 1):

you can try this by using es6 feature template string:-

```
this.comments = `${this.comment1}
${this.comment2}`;
```

When you are using typescript then you should use es6 features to leverage more functionality in code.