# Showing multiple lines in alert (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to show an alert when the user selects the checkbox.We have created alert service as a shared component.Because every module is using that.

My code is like:

```
     if(this.checkboxvalue)
      {
        this.alertservice.error('Hello again! This is how we add line breaks to an alert box!')
      }
```

I want to show the alert like

```
Hello again! This is how we add
line breaks to an alert box!
```

But it displays in a single line.

I tried `\n, \\n ,<br\>`

But nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: according to that tryit it works with '\n'.
Would you please add the code of this.alertservice.error(...)?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert2

Comment: @WorksLikeACharm I show it in a .ts file.I will add the code of alertservice.error. It is not like a browser alert.This alertservice is the one which is custom alert

Comment: I see the error-function now, but how do you consume the subject.next?/how do you show the alert?

Comment: Actually the above code is written as a service.I am using observable in this service and subscriber at another component

Comment: Do you use any library for your alerts?

Comment: If your `alertservice` is injecting the string as HTML, you need a line break tag, which is `<br>` (or `<br/>`), not `<br\>` as you indicate in what you tried. That backslash before the `>` would render the tag ineffective. If the `alertservice` is injecting it as text, you could try `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

User preformatted strings:

```
const msg = `
aaa
bbb
`;
alert(msg);
```

Comment: Paste it in the console and try it.

Comment: console doesn´t sanitize whereas angular does sanitize interpolations like {myError} in it´s template.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `<br/>` and not `<br\>`:

```
message = "Hello again! This is how we add<br/>line breaks to an alert box!"
```

It worked for me.
Please let me know if you need a stackblitz.

Comment: It worked for me. What we need is your real code-snippet.

Comment: You are certainly using a function, that transforms the message/string before showing it.

Comment: le me check @Meziane

Comment: Hi [ramya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12779248/ramya);
have you solved your problem?

Comment: Meziane...  Thank you for your concern. I have solved it

Comment: It wiill be nice if you give us a feedback what was the problem.

Comment: I have solved it by adding innerHTML to the particular div.It works

Comment: As you state @codebuff, this is how it should be solved : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220706/2459449

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to output your error like this in your template:

{myError}

But angular sanitizes the text of myError in {myError} for security reasons. Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts