# How to write function that return string that contains newline in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a function that on output it will write
Hello
World

this is what i have tried and it does not work

```
export function HelloWorld():string{

    return  "Hello"+ "\n"+ "World";
}
```

This is the output that I get
[image: My output]

Comment: Please refer It Might Help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220706/9368328

Comment: Does not work unfortunately

Comment: Can you add Code snippet where you are using HelloWorld??

Comment: Please try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52221221/9368328

Comment: It's not a standard html div manipulation, it's a live output using yarn. Code snippet where I am using HelloWorld is another function that returns this HelloWorld function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you using the `HelloWorld` function and what does it output to?

`console.log(HelloWorld());`

would output

```
Hello
World
```

to the console

```
document.body.innerHTML = HelloWorld();
```

Would output

```
Hello World
```

As innerHTML is expecting HTML so it just takes the input, removes any input that it doesn't like (and presumably replaces with a space, correct me if I'm wrong please).

```
document.body.innerText = HelloWorld();
```

Would output

```
Hello
World
```

As innerText takes your input and replaces special characters & such with their HTML equivalents `\n` becomes `<br />`

*Tip:* For your own sanity (readability is super important in large scripts/repos), functions should always start with a lowercase, classe's & Types with uppercase AKA

`helloWorld` = Function

`HelloWorld` = Class or Type